# StreamWriter not writing data

Tags: c#, .net

I am using StraemWriter to log text messages to a log file. The log file should be created if it doesn't exist, appended to if the file creation date is less than a given time or recreated if created before that time. I am using the class/code below

```
public static class LogIt
{
    private const string LOG_FNAME = @"Logfile.log";

    public static void WriteMsg(string msg)
    {
        bool append = true;
        if (File.Exists(LOG_FNAME))
        {
            //DateTime delDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
            DateTime delDate = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-30);
            DateTime fileCreatedDate = File.GetCreationTime(LOG_FNAME);
            if (DateTime.Compare(fileCreatedDate, delDate) < 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("DELETE FILE");
                File.Delete(LOG_FNAME);
            }
        }

        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(LOG_FNAME, append))
        {
            sw.WriteLine(msg);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(msg);
    }
}
```

This class is used by a simple console app run by the Task Scheduler which runs every x minutes.

The message are written as follows:

```
LogIt.WriteMsg("Log this message");
```

The messages are logged file when the file is initially created however when the file creation date is past the delete date, the file is recreated but no subsequent messages are ever written to the file.

Any ideas on why?

Comment: I reproduced your code and it works fine, are you sure the problem is not somewhere else ?

Comment: @Renen, I have stepped through the code and used console.writeline to output messages and the program appears to work but when the file is deleted then created the sw.Writeline doesn't write the text just an emtpy file is present.

Comment: @Paolo do you see the file being recreated and written to? As the logging works for when the file is initially created.

Comment: Check fileCreatedDate , once you enter in the if you keep going and deleting the file always... fileCreatedDate is not updated

Comment: Yes, the file is recreated and written exactly as it would be expected. OS is Windows 8 64 bit.

Comment: @Mate, Thanks for making me see the obvious. I couldn't understand why the file was blank as even with the FileCreation date problem you and others have described as I expected the last write to still show. Well guess what the last write was an empty string hence the empty file thanks Doh.... I'll accept Rukskan answer but thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@MPD No problem. Here is the implementation of the workaround I suggested. Give it a try and let me know if that works.

```
private const string LOG_FNAME = @"Logfile.log";

        public static void WriteMsg(string msg)
        {
            bool deleted = false;
            bool append = true;
            if (File.Exists(LOG_FNAME))
            {
                //DateTime delDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
                DateTime delDate = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-30);
                DateTime fileCreatedDate = File.GetCreationTime(LOG_FNAME);
                if (DateTime.Compare(fileCreatedDate, delDate) < 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("DELETE FILE");
                    File.Delete(LOG_FNAME);

                    //record that file was deleted and a new one will be created
                    deleted = true;
                }
            }

            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(LOG_FNAME, append))
            {

                sw.WriteLine(msg);

            }

            if (deleted)
            {
                //a new file is created. Make sure the creation time is set
                FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(LOG_FNAME);
                fi.CreationTime = DateTime.Now;
            }

            Console.WriteLine(msg);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

For some reason the file has the initial creation date (first time a file with that path ever created) as the creation date even if it is recreated after deleting. You can check the file properties and see that the log file creation date is always the same. A work around would be to update the file creation date in code whenever you recreate the file. You can use FileInfo class for that.

Comment: [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.getcreationtime.aspx) MSDN entry explains how NTFS might cache this information.

Comment: @Rukshan Perera thanks for the info but I can get to recreate using the f the file but just any subsequent stream write never appear. I shall add code to cater for this but I am not sure that is the cause of the missing write. Thanks also for the MSDN link 500-Internal..

Comment: @MPD No problem. Here is the implementation of the workaround I suggested. Give it a try and let me know if that worked.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are running this code on Windows 2003 (or maybe XP). If so: When you create a file in some directory at time T1 and the delete it and then re-create it; surprise surprise it has T1 as creation date!

I know this just because I had the same problem on Windows 2003!

BTW I use NLog now and (IMHO) it's perfect and has everything I need.